# Crystal Reports Conditional Display

Tags: crystal-reports, notnull

I have 3 fields in a report (say, FIELDA, FIELDB, FIELDC) and want to implement the following pseudocode:

```
IF FIELDA IS NOT NUll, SUPPRESS(hide) (FIELDB AND FIELDC)
ELSE IF FIELDB IS NOT NUll, SUPPRESS (FIELDA AND FIELDC)
ELSE IF FIELDC IS NOT NUll, SUPPRESS (FIELDA AND FIELDB)
```

Also kindly specify where I am to enter the code.

Comment: where do you want to place the fields in design?

Comment: In the details section of design

Answer (score 0):

try this:

In supress part of the details write below code:

```
If Not ISNULL(FIELDA)
Then false
else true
else if Not ISNULL(FIELDB)
Then false
else true
else if Not ISNULL(FIELDC)
Then false
else true
```